# Using counter for scoring

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am recently developing an android wordsearch app for my thesis and I am just learning android development at the same time.

I have this method named `checkAns` to determine if the user have selected the correct word on my wordgrid. This is the code of the method:

```
private boolean checkAns(TextView uTxt, List list) {

    final LinearLayout wordList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wordL);
    String word = uTxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    int isCorrect = 0; // <====== IT DOESN'T INCREMENT! HELP!

    for(int i = 0; i < Category.size ; i ++) {
        if (word.equals(list.get(i))){
            isCorrect++;
            TextView tv = (TextView) wordList.findViewById (i);
            tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            Log.e("OutPut:", String.valueOf(isCorrect));
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Now my problem here is the `isCorrect` variable. It should determine how many correct words the user had selected. But it doesn't increment. I put the `Log` there just to see if it would increment but it always says:

> E/OutPut:: 1

Question: **What should i do here? Is there anything wrong on my logic?**

Any help, comments, answers, are so much appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: What is the value of Category.size?

Comment: it is obvious that your logic is not correct. either your loop cycle is repeated less than what you think as @Oscar mentioned or you have one instance of word in your list so the if statement becomes true once. third possibility is that when you change your word to lowercase, it doesn't match with your strings in list. is word a specific string? if yes how many instance of it exists in your list?

Comment: @OscarLundberg it's either 5, 8, or 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But it does increment. You assign it to 0 and it outputs 1.

Most likely, the problem is in the for loop. It seems to only run one single iteration and therefore `isCorrect` will only increment once.

Check your `Category.size` what value is it? Since it's named with PascalCase i assume that it is a class, and maybe the problem is that you are referencing it as a static class rather than a object reference.

Try instantiating an object of type `Category`

```
Category cat = new Category();
```

Like so. Use that object to change the data in the class, and then check it with `cat.size`

I see no problems with your `isCorrect` variable, but I would suggest that your incremention is the last thing that happens before you close the loop, that way if you need to use its value, it will actually represent the value of the current iteration.

Comment: The value of `Category.size` is a user input integer. ITS value comes from a `RadioButton` consists of (5, 8, 10). `Category` on my project is a `java` class.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the error. I just used `parseInt` the string value of the `TextView()` and subtract it by 1 everytime the user find the correct answers. Thanks for all the help and clearance on my logic!